# How to send Data from Funcation to Html page list in Web Form

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a Application I neaver work on Web Form so simple I have to send a data to html page..

in the First page I have a Button and a listBox

```
<asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button12_Click" />
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

So when I click the button it should send list of user to the list box

```
protected void Button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationDbContext obk = new ApplicationDbContext();
    foreach (var item in obk.Users.ToList())
    {
        ListBox1.Text = item.UserName;

    }
```

First it is not showing the data in the list box

second I want to send a data from C# to Html like in MVC we have ViewData["jsad"] so is there any thing in Web Form I am new in Web Forms I work on MVC so I am so confuse

And you can give me any good web link for tutorial for Web form ,

Comment: Wow!How can you work on MVC without the knowledge of webforms?

Comment: Because I never work on Web Form i work on Ruby on rail which use is MVC then i learn Asp.net mvc with in 10 days but cant able to figure out this Web Form ...Actually what i am trying to do is to assignee some data to a ViewData or TEmpData and return that to the HTml page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add `ListItem` to show `item.UserName` in your `ListBox`.

```
protected void Button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationDbContext obk = new ApplicationDbContext();
    foreach (var item in obk.Users.ToList())
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item.UserName);
    }
}
```

Secondly, I think `Page.Items` is very equivalent to `ViewData`. It's `IDictionary` so you can add and show the value of "jsad" like this.

aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Items["jsad"] = "value";
    // or Page.Items.Add("jsad", "value");
}
```

aspx:

```
<div>jsad = <%: Page.Items["jsad"] %></div>
```

and here is a good reference for MVC developers to understand WebForms.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528117/WebForms-vs-MVC